# What is the shortest way to determine if one number is greater than, less than, or equal to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What is the shortest Excel worksheet formula to compare two numbers and determine whether one is greater than, less than, or equal two the other number?

I know how to do a simple comparison with the <,>,=, etc. operators and I know I can nest IF statements, but I've been trying to figure out if there is a shorter way, such as FUNCTION(X,Y) ==> 1 if <, 2 if >, 3 if =

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
=sign(a1-b1)
```

result is -1,0, or 1

Comment: This is unimprovable. I'm upvoting the somewhat prosaic question just to highlight the excellence of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

*My approach is little different, I've logically tested data in both cells to get value, to justify the test.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `C107:

  `=(A107>B107)*(A107*10)+(A107<=B107)*(A107*5)`

**N.B. :**

- Cell `A107` will be multiplied by `5` if & when `A107` is either `Equals to Or Less` than `B107`.
- Otherwise, if cell `A107` is Greater than `B107`, then multiplied by `10`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*